# Windows batch programing check passed argument value

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying with windows batch command. not Getting the result as expected.

i am passing 4 args to a batch file and inside the batch file i am checking if the 4th arg value is "1"

here the code snippet.

```
IF %%4=="1" (
echo "Error Level is zero"
echo 'Creating web Ears...'
set cd=%CD%
echo "Current Directory: " %cd%
)
```

Even after passing the exact value 1, if condition doesn't evaluate to true. Can someone please identify in mistake?

mybat.bat x 5 c 1

Comment: Instead of using `bat` batch files, take a look at power shell - it is much more powerful.

Answer (score 2):

Found two errors:

- Use just one %
- Remove the double quote around 1

```
IF %4==1 (  
echo "Error Level is zero"  
echo 'Creating web Ears...'  
set cd=%CD%  
echo "Current Directory: " %cd%  
)
```

Tested by Command Prompt on Win7 64bit

Comment: If the fourth parameter is empty, the IF statement will break with a message about syntax error. It would be safer to add characters to both sides of the comparison (typically quotation marks, but that isn't a fixed rule, of course), something like this: `IF "%4" == "1" (…`.